# Mapear objetos pelo Hibernate com os dados "descentralizados"

Tags: hibernate, java-ee

Não sei se o termo descentralizado do título está correto, caso não esteja alguém fique a vontade para mudar. Mas vamos ao que interessa.

Tenho um cenário onde estou desenvolvendo um programa que gerencia monitorias de uma instituição, nas aulas de JavaEE e Hibernate nós fizemos o mapeamento das classes certinho, criei a classe Aluno, por exemplo, coloquei todos os atributos nela, relacionamentos, etc., segue o código:

**Aluno.java**

```
@Entity
public class Aluno implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(length=11, nullable=false)
    private int cpf;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String nome;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private int rg;

    @Column(length=11,nullable=false)
    private int matricula;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataNascimento;

    /* RELACIONAMENTOS */

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="aluno")
    private List<Inscricao> inscricoes;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="aluno")
    private List<Relatorio> relatorios;

    /* GETTERS AND SETTERS */
    ...
}
```

Beleza, funcionando 100%, mas isso dentro de sala de aula, agora estamos passando para a parte de implementação onde iremos consumir dados da instituição, só que no banco de dados deles não tem uma tabela Aluno como eu tenho na minha classe, no banco deles existe uma tabela Aluno que não tem o nome do aluno por exemplo mas contém o ID de uma pessoa, o nome do aluno está na tabela pessoa, e assim por diante, o banco é bastante normalizado.

Agora na prática, como faço pra conseguir consumir os dados com minha atual classe? Que modificações fazer? Como dizer que o atributo nome por exemplo está na tabela pessoa? Pesquisei mas não consegui encontrar, não sei se estou pesquisando pelos termos errados, mas se alguém puder me ajudar, agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para o nome da tabela, você pode utilizar a anotação `@Table`. Você também pode usar `@SecondaryTable` ou `@SecondaryTables` se a entidade estiver dividiva em várias tabelas separadas. Você pode usar `@Inheritance`, `@DiscriminatorColumn` e `@DiscriminatorValue` para mapear herança.

Você deveria fazer o seu mapeamento de entidades refletir o banco de dados e vice-versa. Se isso não ocorre, um dos dois deveria ser mudado. Afinal, o propósito da entidade e das anotações é exatamente descrever para o Hibernate/JPA como é que ocorre o mapeamento objeto-relacional, e portanto se a sua classe `Aluno` é significativamente diferente do que há no banco-de-dados, então um dos dois deve ser alterado para se adequar ao outro.

Você pode mapear views se necessário. O motivo disso ser possível é que o Hibernate/JPA não consegue (ou melhor dizendo, não precisa) distinguir se ele está fazendo `SELECT` em uma tabela ou uma view. No entanto, se você fizer isso, na hora que ele tentar dar um `INSERT`, `UPDATE` ou `DELETE`, você vai ter uma exceção, então só use isso se você tiver certeza que estas operações nunca deverão ocorrer.

---

Exemplo de uso de `@Table` e `@SecondaryTable`:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "xpto") // O nome da tabela no banco de dados é xpto, embora a entidade se chame Aluno.
@SecondaryTables({
    @SecondaryTable(name = "xpto2", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ALUNO_ID"))
    @SecondaryTable(name = "xpto3", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "CHAVE"))
})
public class Aluno implements Serializable {

    @Column(table = "xpto")
    private String foo;

    @Column(table = "xpto2")
    private String bar;

    // ...
}
```

Neste caso, você está dizendo que a entidade `Aluno` está nas tabelas `xpto`, `xpto2` e `xpto3`, sendo `xpto` a tabela principal. As tuplas correspondentes na tabela `xpto2` e `xpto3` são encontradas pelos respectivos campos de chave primária (que devem coincidir com o da `xpto`). Ou seja, há um relacionamento 1-para-1 entre as três (mesmo se o banco-de-dados não impor restrição de integridade, uma vez que você está dizendo isso apenas ao Hibernate/JPA). Ou seja, do ponto de vista do Hibernate/JPA, as tabelas `xpto2` e `xpto3` tem como PK, a FK de `xpto`.

Se o relacionamento entre estas tabelas não for tão simples assim ou o formato das chaves diferir entre um e outro, talvez o melhor seja usar o `@OneToOne` ou alguma outra coisa.

---

Exemplo de uso de `@Inheritance` com estratégia `JOINED`:

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Pessoa implements Serializable {
    // ...
}

@Entity
public class Aluno extends Pessoa {
    // ...
}

@Entity
public class Professor extends Pessoa {
    // ...
}
```

Isso daí faz com que haja uma tabela para `Pessoa`, uma para `Aluno` e uma para `Professor`, aonde a chave primária dos três têm o mesmo formato (ou seja, do ponto de vista do Hibernate/JPA, A PK de `Aluno` é FK de `Pessoa` e a PK de `Professor` é FK de `Pessoa` também). E então:

- Toda tupla inserida na tabela `Aluno` também está na tabela `Pessoa`.
- Toda a tupla inserida na tabela `Professor` também está na tabela `Pessoa`.
- Se uma tupla está na tabela `Pessoa`, ela pode ou não estar em `Aluno` ou `Professor`.

---

Exemplo de uso de `@Inheritance` com estratégia `TABLE_PER_CLASS`:

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Pessoa implements Serializable {
    // ...
}

@Entity
public class Aluno extends Pessoa {
    // ...
}

@Entity
public class Professor extends Pessoa {
    // ...
}
```

Isso daí faz com que haja uma tabela para `Aluno` e uma para `Professor`. Não há tabela para `Pessoa`. Basicamente o mapeamento na tebela de `Pessoa` é copiado-e-colado em cada uma das subclasses.

---

Exemplo de uso de `@Inheritance` com estratégia `SINGLE_TABLE`:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TIPO", discriminatorType = STRING, length = 20)
public class Pessoa implements Serializable {
    // ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ALUNO")
public class Aluno extends Pessoa {
    // ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("PROF")
public class Professor extends Pessoa {
    // ...
}
```

Isso daí coloca os `Aluno`s e os `Professor`es todos na mesma tabela, e tal tabela deve conter todos os campos tanto de `Aluno` quanto de `Professor`. A coluna `TIPO` neste exemplo diferencia se a tupla é um `Aluno` ou um `Professor`. Se for `ALUNO` é `Aluno`. Se for `PROF` é `Professor`.

Comment: Sim @Victor, a minha intenção é transformar minha classe, para que fique de acordo com a tabela, você poderia exemplificar usando essas anotações? Supondo que existe uma tabela aluno que tem a sua matrícula, e tem uma FK para Pessoas, e em pessoas tem o nome da pessoa.

Comment: E se eu tiver uma view, ou uma view materializada? Dá pra simplificar, tipo referenciando na classe em vez de uma tabela, uma view? (não vou fazer inserção, apenas leitura de dados)

Comment: @JoãoNeto Editei a resposta. O que acha dela agora?

Comment: Parabéns Victor, muito boa a resposta! Minha última dúvida é: Como você disse que o jpa/hibernate não difere se é um select ou view eu posso no nome da tabela por o nome da minha view certo? assim: @Table(name = view_Alunos), atentando ao fato de só poder dar select.

Comment: @JoãoNeto É porque na hora de fazer o `SELECT`, não importa se é view ou tabela, isso fica completamente transparente para a aplicação, incluindo o Hibernate/JPA.

Comment: Entendi, beleza, valeu cara. Foi de grande ajuda! :D